# New dimension with coordinates in xarray apply_ufunc

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, vectorization, python-xarray

I have a 3D array of signals with dimensions `('experiment', 'trial', 'time')`.
I am trying to vectorize the computation of Welch's periodogram for each trial of each experiment using `xr.apply_ufunc` with `scipy.signal.welch`, but cannot get it to work around the dimensions. `scipy.signal.welch` returns two arrays, the frequencies and the PSD/power spectrum.

Creating random data:

```
    data = xr.DataArray(
        np.random.random((3, 2, 1024)),
        dims=['experiment', 'trial', 'time'],
        coords={
            'experiment': np.arange(3),
            'trial': np.arange(2),
            'time': np.arange(1024),
        },
    )
```

Now applying scipy.sig.welch for 1D input:

```
    ret = xr.apply_ufunc(
        sig.welch,
        data,
        input_core_dims=[['trial', 'time']],
        output_core_dims=[['frequency'], []],
        vectorize=True,
    )
```

throws

> TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> ....
> numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2506, in _vectorize_call_with_signature
> output[index] = result
>
> ```
> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
> ```

Probably the numpy vectorization expects the returned values to be scalars?
Since sig.welch can work on 2D arrays, another attempt:

```
    ret = xr.apply_ufunc(
        sig.welch,
        data,
        input_core_dims=[['trial', 'time']],
        output_core_dims=[['trial', 'frequency'], []],
        vectorize=True,
    )
```

and this throws:

> ... numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2050, in _update_dim_sizes
> raise ValueError(
> ValueError: 1-dimensional argument does not have enough dimensions for all core dimensions ('dim2', 'dim0')

Is there a way to do the vectorization, or must one loop through the top level dimension?